# Step by step guide for new users on how to post content?

Tags: wp-admin, dashboard

I'm trying to find a way to guide new authors on the dashboard of how post content, but I can't find any plugin or tutorial about how do it, if I try to look on google I keep finding "how create a dashboard plugin: step by step", "authors: step by step guide" etc.

I don't know hoe find some useful answer on google

Comment: Are you trying to create a wizard or a tutorial of some sort or are you just looking to either put point form steps in the dashboard or perhaps link to a PDF guide?  I can help with the latter as I've done it for clients to show them how to use custom post-types and how to use custom functionality I've added to their WordPress.

Comment: I'm trying to create a tutorial, something like the same way Wordpress show you pop ups the first time you install it, but I want it for custom posts so the authors get oriented on how add content

Comment: Hmmm, I've never actually done that myself or even really thought about how it's done.  For starters I'd look at adding a value to the user meta that you can check to see if the person has already done and dismissed the tutorial. You would add the tooltips to the wp admin footer area and then use CSS to position them properly, but be careful to make sure they only load on pages where they're relevant - also only load them if the user meta shows they haven't 'dismissed' or 'completed' the tutorial.  Then you'd have to apply javascript/jQuery for the interactive bit.

Comment: So you'd have `display:block` on the first one, and all the rest of the tips would have `display:none` and then as users clicked 'next' on the tips, it would close tip and change the display value of the next one.  You could probably put all of this together in a few hours depending on how complex you wanted it to be, etc.  Probably even be best to create a temporary user account and try grabbing the HTML structure and CSS of the default WP tooltips.